# How does SonarQube duplication ratio assessment/grading matrix decided?

Tags: sonarqube, code-duplication, software-quality

I generally use SonarQube for performing static code analysis of on going projects to detect best pratice violations and possible anomalies.(Also using SonarLint plugin but it's out of scope.) I know that keeping duplication ratio as low as possible is important as having graded with A for Reliability, Security and Maintainability metrics. However, how much low is desired for a software project? SonarQube(Version 6.7.1 (build 35068)) uses [this matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rN2B.png) for duplication ratio assesment.

Searched for source of the values used in matrix and read all the web pages that come up in first 3 pages of searh results. However, all that I could find was related with how duplication ratio of SonarQube works and is configured, importance of keeping dupliation ratio low(any number is not mentioned) and SonarQube features that guides users on solving duplications.

After not being able to find any results in SonarQube domain, I expanded my researches to learn what is desired and acceptable duplication ratio for a software. Again couldn't find any numbers except some sites that states it should be zero which seems some unrealistic to me.

Could someone justify how the values used in matrix are decided? Why below 3 is graded as A, instead of 4?

Answer (score 0):

The formula to calculate code duplication is

```
Duplicated lines (%) = Density of duplication = Duplicated lines / Lines * 100
```

as per the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions#MetricDefinitions-Duplications).

You can configure the duplication rules yourself:

[image]

This is also documented [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Duplications).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, these links are not providing the information I am looking for. I already checked them. I want to learn how the values used in matrix(check the question for link) are decided and how much low duplication ratio is desired for a software project?